# Push notifications in hybrid mobile app

Tags: ios, push-notification, hybrid-mobile-app

My app is a hybrid mobile. It has one View Controller in native swift code, and inside there's a webview that loads my web app. I am a little confused how to implement push notifications for such structure. What I have in mind right now is to subscribe to a cloud-based channel (e.g. parse or pusher) inside the web app, and when it gets a message it makes the device to show a push notification. It will look like

1. The native ios wrapper will subscribe to a channel.
2. Webview will push a message to a channel, specifying a userId.
3. The native ios wrapper gets the message since he subscribed to the channel.

However at step 3, he should only get the notification if his userId matches the userId specified in the message. How do I connect the userId (of the logged in user) that resides inside the web app with the native wrapper?

Comment: In plain English, are you looking for a technique for the JavaScript inside the Webview to somehow communicate with the iOS application?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are looking at communicating back and forth between the hosted web app and the host `UIWebView`.

### Communicate with Javascript

In a class adopting the `UIWebViewDelegate` (to ensure that your web app is fully loaded), invoke a `javascript` method:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIWebViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var webView: UIWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "SO-32322397",
                                    ofType: "html")
        let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path!, isDirectory: false)
        let request = URLRequest(url: url)
        self.webView.loadRequest(request)
    }

    //MARK: UIWebViewDelegate
    
    func webViewDidFinishLoad(_ webView: UIWebView) {
        let userID =
            webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from: "userID()")
        if let userID = userID {
            print("userID = \(userID)")
        }
    }
}
```

---

► Find this solution on [GitHub](https://github.com/SwiftArchitect/SO-32322397) and additional details on [Swift Recipes](http://swiftarchitect.com/recipes/#SO-32322397).